# Customising behaviour - toggle class- popover - Angular UI bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I'm wanting to add active classes to elements when various Angular UI directives are called. For example when I call the popover i'd like to highlight the element (which in this [case is a button](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bullrout/LrpmQ/3/show/)). I know that I can just add ng-click with an expression but I want a more robust solution.

I'm not sure how to modify the [directive(s)](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/popover) so I'm able to obtain the target element and toggle the class. I have created a fiddle and I was hoping that someone can assist with this.

I appreciate the help guys, thanks.

Comment: The fiddle isn't working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular does not restrict you from defining directives with the same name as those in ui-bootstrap. That does not mean you override them (although you could), you merely apply them additively. As long as you don't break their original functionality, you can do something like:

```
app.directive("popover", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    priority: -1000, // Run last
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.addClass("my-popover");
      scope.$watch('tt_isOpen', function (value) {
        if (value) {
          element.addClass("open");
        } else {
          element.removeClass("open");
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive("tooltip", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    priority: -1000, // Run last
    link: function (scope, element) {
      element.addClass("my-tooltip");
      scope.$watch('tt_isOpen', function (value) {
        if (value) {
          element.addClass("open");
        } else {
          element.removeClass("open");
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And then define styles like:

```
.my-popover.open {
    background-color: red; 
}

.my-tooltip.open {
    font-style:italic;
    color: orange;
}
```

Unfortunately, you are a bit dependent on the original implementation details (*where on earth did this `tt_isOpen` came from*).

Check it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dG3W6eYQlqz3665xWCFX?p=preview).

Comment: That's great. Thanks for such a concise answer. Very helpful.

Comment: Very good.   Also, if you wanted to change the tooltip text, say give it a different font, you can obtain the next sibling element right on open and add a class to it.